# Golang: calling methods of embedded types

Tags: go, inheritance, methods, types

I'm using the Golang 1.20 compiler and there is a strange behavior related to type embedding which I do not understand.

In one first package called graphutil, I created a Graph type structure, with several methods (such as Graph.AddNode()):

Package "graphutil":

```
type Graph struct {}

func (self *Graph) AddNode() {}
```

In another package called neuronutil, I created a child structure of graph, called NeuralNetwork:

Package "neuronutil":

```
type NeuralNetwork struct {
  *graphutil.Graph
}
```

In theory, I should be able to define a method for neural network which could call a method of Graph, like this:

```
func (self NeuralNetwork) AddNeuron() {
 self.AddNode()
}
```

Yet this is refused by the compiler, which tells me that the NeuralNetwork type does not have an "AddNode" method, although NeuralNetwork should inherit the "AddNode" method from Graph. Of course, the "neuronutil" package imports the "graphutil" package.

**The strange aspect:** if I create a main program, which imports the "graphutil" and "neuronutil" libraries, I can create a neuralnetwork object and call the "AddNode" method from this object. The code below works.

```
func main() {
testnode := graphutil.NewNode(0)
testneuralnetwork := neuronutil.NewNeuralNetwork("Test Neural Network")
testneuralnetwork.AddNode(testnode)
}
```

Does anyone understand why calling the "AddNode" method of the Graph structure works in the main, but not in the neuronutil library ?

Here is a screenshot of the error message:
[image]

**The error message is:** self.AddNode undefined (type NeuralNetwork has no field or method AddNode)compilerMissingFieldOrMethod)

The Graph.AddNode() method does exist.

Comment: Go does not have inheritance, do not try to use embedding as inheritance or it's just going to lead to confusion. Exactly what is the error you see? Delegating to the embedded method compiles just fine: https://go.dev/play/p/T0wp_X84tTz

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The exact setting is a little more complex than the code you posted, which does compile indeed.

Comment: Then we really need a [mre], because what you are describing is not possible

Comment: Perhaps it’s only a problem with the editor, can you compile it from the cli?

Comment: Indeed you are right. The code compiles. Very strange behavior indeed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks like the issue solved. I just want to mention one more time that there is no inheritance in Go. Embedding is composition. You may think that Go generates methods for such calls. For example: self.AddNode() -> func (self NeuralNetwork) AddNode() {
 self.Graph.AddNode()
}